# Find the minimum absolute difference of a number from a number which in the form b^x where b,x > 1

Tags: algorithm, math

Consider an example `70` in which closest number is `64` i.e `2^6`. So minimum absolute difference is `6`.
What will be a **good approach** to this type of problem (`lg n` time complexity)?

Edit: `b` and `x` are `integers`

Edit: `1 < n < 10^9` where `n` is the number whose minimum absolute difference has to be found. Suppose `q` queries are coming and `1 < q < 10^5`

Comment: Should b and x be integers?

Comment: @DavidZ Should be because otherwise `2^6.1292830169` is very close to 70 and with more precision the difference will tend to `0`.

Comment: @user3419726 Can you give an upper bound to the value of the number to be checked?

Comment: Is this a competition, or homework? You seem to have a [buddy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921999/find-nearest-number-to-n-which-can-be-written-in-exponential-form) working on the same problem.

Comment: It was a `competition` without any `editorials`

Comment: Yeah `8^2` also works fine @ringø

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find k'th roots of your number, for all reasonable values of k, rounding up and down, and finding which produces the value nearest to n.

You can stop this algorithm once the k'th root of n is less than 2, which means there's O(log n) roots to find.

Here's some Python code implementing this:

```
import math

def nearest_pow(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    best = n
    for k in xrange(2, n):
        p = math.pow(n, 1.0 / k)
        for x in xrange(2):
            best = min(best, abs((int(p) + x) ** k - n))
        if int(p) == 1:
            break
    return best

print nearest_pow(70)
```

The terminating condition `int(pow(n, 1/k)) == 1` occurs when k is at most lg(n)+1, so this algorithm is O(log n), assuming math.pow is O(1).

Comment: How is it `log n` solution when `k` is in range `[2,n]`? @Paul

Comment: @user3419726 is it not explained in the answer? There's a break in the loop, which occurs when `int(pow(n, 1/k)) == 1`.

Comment: This is used `n^(1/logn)` == 1

Comment: How is the output from `nearest_pow` to be interpreted? (`nearest_pow(70)` gives `6`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson it returns the difference between n and the nearest power a^b where a, b > 1. It's probably not the best name for the function, but I thought it was clear enough given the question and the example in the question.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Ah, sorry; I'm an idiot. I missed the bit where the OP was explicitly looking for the absolute difference.

Comment: What is the use of : for x in xrange(2). Why is the arg 2?

Comment: @AdityaJoshee it tries p rounded down, and rounded up. xrange(2) takes the values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution with `O(sqrt(n))` complexity. For a given number `n`, let `k = ceil(sqrt(n))`. Now, the minimum absolute difference can be calculated with the following Python code:

```
import math
n = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
k = int(math.sqrt(n))
minimum = 2147486347
for i in range(2, k+1):
    p = int(math.log(n)/math.log(i))

    if p > 1:
        minimum = min(minimum, abs(n-i**p))
    if p >= 1:
        minimum = min(minimum, abs(n-i**(p+1)))


print minimum
```

Comment: Approach seems `pretty good` but a `log n` solution is needed

Comment: Try `124`, the min is 1 ( 5^3 ) but the algo gives 3 ( 11^2 )

Comment: @ringø Corrected it. I was only checking for the perfect powers below `n`. Now I am also checking a perfect power above `n`.